# How are the mainstream websites maintained?

Tags: web-applications, web

By "mainstream websites" I mean websites like newyorktimes.com, msnbc.com etc, so what CMS(or is there any) or method do they usually use to update/maintain their websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems MSNBC, and a lot of other huge sites I imagine, have in-house teams developing and maintaining a custom CMS. Here's an interesting blog post by one of the developers about their new CMS structure: http://jtbennett.com/blog/2010/07/database-oriented-architecture-is-doa and the development team have started a behind-the-scenes blog: http://development.msnbc.msn.com/

As for mainstream sites that don't have a custom CMS, it seems that Drupal is becoming the popular choice. Users include the US government, the French government, the British post office, the Economist, Universal Music, etc.: http://www.whousesdrupal.com/